# Maya Mel | Creation of capsule with modelling operations applied. Problems with executing twice

Tags: attributes, rename, maya, mel

So the problem I'm having is the most simple in terms of programming, but I'm a mel noob and artist not really a coder so I'm completely clueless with this stuff.

[image]

The thing I'm trying to do is create a cylinder with 8 divisions [first object from the left], then turn on round caps with a division of 4[second object from left], then select specific edges and remove them [second from right] Once this is done apply a linear smooth.[far right]

The problem I'm having while chopping up code to make scripts is the fact when I create an item(object) it has a different name on each execute, forcing my script to burn brighter than the Hindenburg.

So my current mess of a script was

```
polyCylinder -r 1 -h 2 -sx 8 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0 -rcp 0 -cuv 3 -ch 1;
setAttr "polyCylinder1.roundCap" 1;
setAttr "polyCylinder1.subdivisionsCaps" 4;
select -r pCylinder1.e[131] ;
select -r pCylinder1.e[129] pCylinder1.e[131] ;
select -r pCylinder1.e[129] pCylinder1.e[131] pCylinder1.e[135] ;
select -r pCylinder1.e[129] pCylinder1.e[131] pCylinder1.e[133] pCylinder1.e[135] ;
select -r pCylinder1.e[123] pCylinder1.e[129] pCylinder1.e[131] pCylinder1.e[133] pCylinder1.e[135] ;
select -r pCylinder1.e[121] pCylinder1.e[123] pCylinder1.e[129] pCylinder1.e[131] pCylinder1.e[133] pCylinder1.e[135] ;
select -r pCylinder1.e[121] pCylinder1.e[123] pCylinder1.e[127] pCylinder1.e[129] pCylinder1.e[131] pCylinder1.e[133] pCylinder1.e[135] ;
select -r pCylinder1.e[121] pCylinder1.e[123] pCylinder1.e[125] pCylinder1.e[127] pCylinder1.e[129] pCylinder1.e[131] pCylinder1.e[133] pCylinder1.e[135] ;
polyDelEdge -cv true -ch 1 pCylinder1.e[121] pCylinder1.e[123] pCylinder1.e[125] pCylinder1.e[127] pCylinder1.e[129] pCylinder1.e[131] pCylinder1.e[133] pCylinder1.e[135];
```

So with that script it works, but only once as the issue is I'm calling for a name which is only there once, after I've executed the script it no longer uses the same name.
I then thought it would be possible using the select object way of doing it as I assumed it would eradicate all the drivel in my kitbashed code by using

```
string $array[] = `ls -sl`;
for ($item in $array)
{
setAttr ($item + ".roundCap") 1;
setAttr ($item + ".subdivisionsCaps") 4;
}
```

But as you probably already know, this doesn't work because the item name is not the input name :/ but I couldn't find how to call it. So, can anyone here possibly help and maybe explain also as I'm trying to learn this language somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out with the help of reddit, didn't think they would help before stack overflow but they did.

Here's how to set the string name and it will change every time.

```
//set name
string $startName = "capsule1";
//cName Capsule perams
string $cName[] = `polyCylinder -rcp 1 -sx 8 -sc 4 -ch 1 -r 1 -h 2 -n $startName`;
```